# Why in kernel code some addresses of variables are stored in char pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel

I was going through the kernel source code and I found this statement:

```
char *tagp = NULL;

/* ...CODE... */

tagp = &descriptor->b_data[sizeof(journal_header_t)];
```

I wonder **why** this address is stored in a char pointer rather than any other type more related to what it represents, such as maybe `void` if this is an opaque.

Comment: Maybe they want to perform pointer-arithmatic on it, avoiding excessive casts. This, for instance, seems like a way to emulate `offsetof()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The individual cases may have their explicit use-cases, but in general, this is useful for two reasons.

- a `char` pointer has the same alignment requirement as a `void` pointer.
- `char` pointer can be used to access (via dereference) any other type of data, starting from lowest addressed byte of the object (Successive increments of the
  result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.). Also, pointer arithmatic (if needed, is allowed on `char` pointer, not on `void` pointers).

Thus, using a `char *` is more robust.

Comment: So it is actually low-level byte addressing of the memory.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an old code then the type `char *`  was used instead of the type `void *` because the type `void` was absent in the C at that time.

Comment: This appears to be code from the last decade and Linux has been using void * from 0.01.

Comment: @Art I just mentioned one of reasons when you can encounter char * instead of void *.:) I did not see the kernel myself.

Comment: I just got curious so I dug around a bit and reported my findings.

Comment: For low-level byte addressing of the memory, char pointer seems more natural than sizeless void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the kernel we need to do some operatings on byte.And then we can do operatings like &,<<,>>.